# How can I stop my skin from peeling?

Tags: personal-care, weather

After I get a sunburn the next day my skin starts to peel. Is there a easy way to at least temporarily stop this from occurring?

Comment: This might be a reasonable question for our [Health site](http://health.stackexchange.com) — please check the scope there — but this is not in need of a life hack in the context of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using some aloe vera or lotion that has aloe vera in it. It has a cooling effect that will reduce inflammation and slow the peeling.